# View variable's value of a running python script in local machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have this script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
for i in range(1000):
    sleep 10
```

I executed it, and the PID is 3030, let's say i need to know the value of `i`, how can i retrieve it?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Have you tried to print the value like `print(i)` ?

Comment: I can add print statement to the script before executing script, what if i executed the script before that, and while it is running i need to know some variable value at current time.
Note: i don't need to kill/terminate script, adding print statement and execute script again.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use some logging library because you need to control running state of the process and it's outputs. As example you may use this: https://github.com/Delgan/loguru